# Regex matching string BAR as long as string FOO does not occur before it

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that is only true of a string contains BAR that is not preceded by FOO.

For example, the regex WOULD NOT match this:

```
FOO IS BAR
```

But WOULD match this:

```
BAZ IS BAR
```

Comment: What language is this you're using? What is the command you've executed? What is your input/expected output?

Comment: @Rubens I'm using PHP's ereg method to compare a string (a syslog message) to a regex statement.  I'm not sure that the question is language specific though.

Comment: Yes, it is. Regex implementations vary wildly from language to language. That's why the regex FAQ asks to always tag a question with the relevant language. Also, `ereg` has been deprecated for a long time.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - thank you, I didn't know that.  And yes, I agree ereg is depreciated.  It's an in-house app that I'm forced to work with.

Answer (score 4):

```
(?<!FOO.*)BAR
```

is the correct regex for this (but it only works with the .NET regex engine).

`(?<!FOO.*)` is a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts that it's not possible to match any string containing `FOO` before the current position.

In PHP, you don't have infinite lookbehind. An alternative would be

```
^(?:(?!FOO|BAR).)*BAR
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     # Start of string
(?:   # Match...
 (?!  # (unless the following can be matched here:
  FOO #  either FOO
 |    #  or
  BAR #  BAR)
 )    # (end of lookahead)
 .    # ... any character.
)*    # Repeat as needed
BAR   # Match BAR
```

However, even this doesn't work with the deprecated `ereg` functions. You need `preg` functions in order to be able to use lookaround assertions.

But I think there is a way that works with `ereg`:

```
^(FO?|[^FO]|[^O]O)*BAR
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
(      # Either match:
 FO?   # F or FO
|      # or
 [^FO] # any character except F or O
|      # or
 [^O]O # any non-O character followed by O
)*     # any number of times
BAR    # Then match BAR
```

However, this will get very complicated very quickly if your exclusion string is more complicated than `FOO`...

Comment: You could make `*` reluctant causing the `BAR` alternative to be safely removed: `^(?:(?!FOO).)*?BAR` (or am I missing something?)

Comment: I believe this is the answer, however, I can't get it to work with my specific strings.  RTMT (FOO) & CertExpiry (BAR).

Comment: @DanB.: Sorry, I have been editing again - I just found out that `ereg` doesn't even support lazy quantifiers. That said, I don't think there's a way that works with `ereg`, at least not in all circumstances.

Comment: @TimPietzcker OK, no problem.  You've provided a lot of info here and I'm sure it will help a lot of ppl!  I'll recommend we move to preg asap!  Thanks!

Comment: @DanB.: Wait, wait! I think I've got it. Please test it and see if that works. But in any way, do move to preg!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex

```
^(?=.*BAR)(?!.*?FOO.*?BAR).*$
 --------- --------------
     |           |
     |           |proceed only if there's no FOO before BAR...
     |->proceed only if there's a BAR...CHEERS..
```

Comment: That's a good solution in the case that a non-.NET language is being used.

Comment: There is one problem: It will fail on `BAR FOO BAR` (where it should match the first `BAR`).

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to put it into two regexes.  If we're talking Perl, for example, you could do

```
if ( /BAR/ && !/FOO.*BAR/ )
```

which to me is much clearer than trying to do the negative lookbehind.

Since you seem to be in PHP, I see nothing wrong with a preg_match on `/BAR/` and another on not matching `/FOO.*BAR/`.